# Find and replace first double-quote before special character via grep

Tags: regex, replace, sed, grep, xargs

I have a whole bunch of files that all have blocks of text in them that look like this:

```
"Each file has different text between the opening double-quote
and the closing right-quote (or whatever it's called)”
```

Perhaps not relevant, but in the past I have used `grep` to do a search and replace like this:

`grep -Rl 'search' ./path/to/files/ | xargs sed -i 's/search/replace/g`

Is there any way to do something similar, but use a regex to replace the opening plain old double-quote with a left-quote (`“`)? The only reliable way to replace the correct double-quote characters is to search on the right-quote, then backwards tot he previous double-quote. I think. I'm just not sure if that's possible or how to do it.

I could just do it with a PHP script, but then I wouldn't get to see if it's possible from the command line.

Comment: Is there newline between 2 lines?

Comment: No, sorry. That was just to prevent the horizontal scrollbar in SO.

Comment: ok good to know, so you just want to replace `”` with `"`?

Comment: No, I want to replace `"` with `“`.

Comment: "The only reliable way"? If all straight double quotes are wrong and all closing double quotes are correct, then you only need to replace straight to open double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sed:

```
sed -i.bak 's/"\([^”]*”\)/“\1/' file

cat file
“Each file has different text between the opening double-quote and the closing right-quote (or whatever it's called)”
```

Comment: Perfect. Here's what I ended up using: `grep -Rl '”' ./dir/ | xargs sed -i.bak 's/"\([^”]*”\)/“\1/'` I didn't know about `.bak`. Very useful. I'm not the best with regex, but it looks like what this is doing is searching for the whole string including the quotes on either end, then replacing only the first character. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes it searches normal quote `"` then 0 or more character that are not `”` that are followed  by `”`.